# How to get accessToken from firebase

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) to sign into my App. I want to retrieve "accessToken" from "stsTokenManager" Object. How can I get it? Following is the response from above line of code:

```
Object {
"apiKey": "", 
"appName": "[DEFAULT]",
"authDomain": "myApp-5e47b.firebaseapp.com",
"createdAt": "1589567878396",
"displayName": "TestFirstName",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"emailVerified": false,
"isAnonymous": false,
"lastLoginAt": "1589617057893",
"phoneNumber": null,
"photoURL": null,
"providerData": Array [
Object {
  "displayName": "TestFirstName",
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "phoneNumber": null,
  "photoURL": null,
  "providerId": "password",
  "uid": "test@gmail.com",
},
],
"redirectEventId": null,
"stsTokenManager": Object {
"accessToken": "",    
"apiKey": "",
"expirationTime": 1589620681845,
"refreshToken": "",
},
"tenantId": null,
"uid": "",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get user access token by following snippet

```
const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
```

To force refresh token

```
const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true);
```

Comment: I did that but it does not return an access token. It returns something like this:
B {
  "a": 0,
  "b": Xb {
    "a": null,
    "b": [Function anonymous],
    "c": true,
    "f": undefined,
    "g": [Function anonymous],
    "next": null,

Comment: it is a promise, you need to await it. update the answer

Comment: @TuanLuong can you please provide me import statement . I am using react js